# Custom Expandable Listview add button

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

1 as shown in the picture section I did that part. However, I need to add a sub-entity before the place is like and I could not find how to do number 2 parts.

[image]

XML Code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#858585"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />


    <ListView
         android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
         android:layout_width="240dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="end"
         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
         android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
         android:dividerHeight="0dp"
         android:background="#858585"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: where is `<ListView
         android:id="@+id/right_drawer"`??

Comment: Can you point List and  Expandable List in the image?

Comment: `<ListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"` not important. Parties with significant left @Stella

Comment: Expandable list point 1. this picture not include listview that part does not matter anyway @SweetWisherツ

Comment: Did you try my code?? any help ?

Comment: yes try it. but left menu slider not open and close. always open left slider

Comment: That's not the XML issue. You need to dig into JAVA code for it

Comment: XML issue because not add  android:layout_gravity="start"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64627/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-metin).

Comment: tnks for advice :) @SweetWisherツ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Layout in *Relative layout* with the property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`  to align it at bottom :

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

   <!-- whatever the control you want here -->
   <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#858585"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not listview, ExpandableListView.

Comment: then change it with `ExpandableListView`